# How to get paragraph element to next line

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag followed by a p tag. The p tag doesn't start from a new line instead is inline with div.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>fd   frgf tfytfy tfytfyf fyfytf xdx fhgg</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
               <input type="text" name="address" required="">
               <label>Enter here</label>
               <span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Show Results" name="" class="btn">
        </form>
     </div>
     <p>want this p tag right below the div</p>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700&display=swap');

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #151515;
}
.container h2{
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.input-field
{
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]
{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field label
{
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #555;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus + label,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid + label
{
  transform: translateY(-35px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff006a;
  padding : 2px 6px;
}
.input-field span
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
}
.input-field span:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00b0ff;
  transform : scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus ~ span:before,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid ~ span:before
{
  transform : scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn
{
  margin-top:20px;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover
{
  background:#00bcd4;

}
```

I tried using a break tag between the p tag and div tag and also tried `display: block;`  neither of them worked. What would be the right way of getting the paragraph element below the div element instead of its right side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that you have added a display : flex  for the body , so the items inside the body will try to  stand in line rather than staying one after another

to solve this issue , remove display:flex from the body

Comment: Also, if there's a specific design intention for `display: flex`, you could set it `flex-direction: column;` so that it flows vertically.

Answer (score -1):

just add it on it's own div wait I will update the answer

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700&display=swap');

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #151515;
}
.container h2{
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.input-field
{
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]
{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field label
{
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #555;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus + label,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid + label
{
  transform: translateY(-35px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff006a;
  padding : 2px 6px;
}
.input-field span
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
}
.input-field span:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00b0ff;
  transform : scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus ~ span:before,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid ~ span:before
{
  transform : scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn
{
  margin-top:20px;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover
{
  background:#00bcd4;

}
p{
margin-top:2rem;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>fd   frgf tfytfy tfytfyf fyfytf xdx fhgg</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
               <input type="text" name="address" required="">
               <label>Enter here</label>
               <span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Show Results" name="" class="btn">
        </form>
        <p>want this p tag right below the div</p>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why adding `p{margin-top:2rem;}` to a demo example? *"just add it on it's own div wait I will update the answer"* cannot be an answer first paragraph. Please be more concise in answering the details of your changes that lead to your solution.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so that it could look better. Ok, sir from next time i will keep in mind this.

Answer (score -1):

Just simply add the p tag inside the div instead of writing it outside the div...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700&display=swap');

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #151515;
}
.container h2{
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.input-field
{
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]
{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field label
{
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #555;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus + label,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid + label
{
  transform: translateY(-35px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff006a;
  padding : 2px 6px;
}
.input-field span
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
}
.input-field span:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00b0ff;
  transform : scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.input-field input[type="text"]:focus ~ span:before,
.input-field input[type="text"]:valid ~ span:before
{
  transform : scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn
{
  margin-top:20px;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover
{
  background:#00bcd4;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>fd   frgf tfytfy tfytfyf fyfytf xdx fhgg</h2>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
               <input type="text" name="address" required="">
               <label>Enter here</label>
               <span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Show Results" name="" class="btn">
        </form>
        <p>want this p tag right below the div</p>
     </div>
</body>
```